# How to send and receive a canfd isotp message using PYTHON-CAN through VECTOR DEVICE VN5610A?

Tags: python, can-bus, python-can

I am getting the following error when executing the below code:

```
  File "D:/evs_framework/tests/Integration/testcases/can_vec.py", line 7, in <module>
    receive_own_messages=True)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\Python36\lib\site-packages\can\interface.py", line 127, in __new__
    return cls(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\Python36\lib\site-packages\can\interfaces\vector\canlib.py", line 125, in __init__
    hw_channel, vxlapi.XL_BUS_TYPE_CAN)
  File "C:\LegacyApp\Python36\lib\site-packages\can\interfaces\vector\vxlapi.py", line 207, in check_status
    raise VectorError(result, xlGetErrorString(result).decode(), function.__name__)
can.interfaces.vector.exceptions.VectorError: xlGetApplConfig failed (XL_ERROR)
```

My code is

```
bus = VectorBus(channel=3, bitrate=500000, fd=True, data_bitrate=2000000, app_name="CANoe")
addr = isotp.Address(isotp.AddressingMode.Normal_11bits, rxid=0x3C1, txid=0x3E)
stack = isotp.CanStack(bus, address=addr, error_handler=my_error_handler, params={'can_fd': True})
stack.send(data)
```

Comment: Is there an entry `CANoe` in the vector hardware config? If so, how does it look like?

Comment: @M.Spiller Honestly, I don't know about that.

Comment: Well, that is what the error message is telling you. It tries to read the application configuration (`xlGetApplConfig`) for application `CANoe` and fails.

Comment: @M.Spiller Thanks, I have re-installed the can hardware drivers and vxlapi.dll, Now it works as expected.